# php variable will not display in email

Tags: php

The assignment I'm working on (an E-commerce course) asks that I use php to generate a new password for a user and send the user an email with the new password. I successfully generate the password, send the email from my school's server to myself (a gmail account), using  php mail() however the php variable representing the password is always blank. I have been looking for answers to this on here and other websites but cannot find what I'm doing wrong. 
I am looking to solve this particular issue and am not looking to use PHPMailer or some other alternative. Also I am not looking to discuss more secure ways to send email, or discuss encryption, just looking to discuss this particular issue and why it is or isn't working. Thank you in advance for any advice.

```
if ($mysqli->conect_errno) {
        die("Error: Could not connect to database." . $mysqli->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo "<p>Connected<br></p>";
    }

    $email = $_POST['email_input'];
    try {
        $password = reset_password($email, $mysqli);
        notify_password($email, $password, $mysqli);
        echo 'Your password has changed and has been emailed to you.<br>';
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Your password could not be reset';
    }

    function reset_password($email, $mysqli){
        $new_password = randomString(8, 12);
        if ($new_password == false) {
            throw new Exception('could not generate new password');
        }
        $rand_number = rand(0, 999);
        $new_password .= $rand_number;
        echo "NEW PASSWORD: " .$new_password."\r\n";

        $query = "UPDATE registration 
        SET password = sha1('".$new_password."')
        WHERE email = '".$email."'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if($result) {
            echo "<br>Password Reset<br>";
        }else {
            echo "An error has occured";
        }

    }
    function randomString($min_length, $max_length){
        return substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), $min_length, $max_length);       
    }

    function notify_password($email, $password, $mysqli){
        $query = "SELECT email FROM registration WHERE email='".$email."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception('could not find email address');
        }else if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
            throw new Exception('Could not find email address:user not in database');    
        }else {
            $row = $result->fetch_object();
            $email = $row->email;
            $from = "From support@HelpFinder \r\n";
            $mesg = "Your password has been changed to ".$password."\r\n"."Please change it the next time you log in.\r\n";

            if(mail($email, 'HelpFinder Login Information', $mesg, $from)) {
                return true;
            }else {
                throw new Exception('Could not send email.');
            }
        }

    }
```

[the email message that arrives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjN8S.png)

[example from text book I'm learning from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj76l.png)

Comment: How are you calling `notify_password`? Are you sure you passed the password into the function? Also, it's frowned upon to post an image of your code instead of the code itself.

Comment: Please post the code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are sending the $password variable as parameter correctly, 
may be its empty

Comment: Yes thank you, you are correct. I did not include the return statement and so my variable was empty.
`$result = $mysqli->query($query);
            if(!$result) {
                throw new Exception('Could not change password.');
                //echo "<br>Password Reset<br>";
            }else {
                return $new_password;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

First please check that you have a double $result before the if declaration.

```
$result = $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

After that you could try to make a var_dump to $password variable to check if it was correctly passed to the notify_password function. You could also post the $password variable definition so we could check in more depth.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, I made the correction. I still have the problem but thank you for spotting that error.